# Em que momento votos de amigos são considerados "Manipulações de Votos"?

Tags: debate, suporte

> Devo ressaltar que esta pergunta não está relacionada a nenhum caso de manipulação de votos, e sim uma dúvida real que não foi encontrada na [central de ajuda do site.](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/search?q=votos)

É sabido que existem usuários que possuem uma certa afinidade com determinados usuários, o que pode acabar acarretando em votos positivos. Claro, nesse caso os critérios para votos ficam claramente menores. Porém, só pelo motivo de ser "amigo" no site, o voto não é válido?

Outro ponto que vale ressalvar é o **trabalho**. Hoje, diversas equipes inteiras procuram o **StackOverflow** para retirar dúvidas. Seja o SOpt, SOen, SOes ou qualquer outro da rede. Com isso, acabamos compartilhando informações com colegas de trabalho, o que também pode gerar votos. Isso é errado? Visto que os votos poderiam vir do mesmo endereço de IP (público), se tratando do mesmo local de trabalho.

E por fim, quando falamos de amigos não podemos esquecer das redes sociais. Diversas pessoas postas respostas em **blogs/Facebook/Twitter** o que acaba também gerando votos e visualizações (esse já houveram alguns problemas no SOen por questões de manipulações de views, mas não vem ao caso). Porém, se não é algo válido, por que existe o botão de compartilhar a resposta/pergunta com redes sociais?

[image: Redes sociais]

Diante desse breve contexto, vem minhas dúvidas reais:

- #### Posso votar em respostas de amigos?
- #### Posso votar em respostas de usuários que estão na mesma "internet" que a minha?
- #### Posso votar em respostas compartilhadas por colegas de trabalho?
- #### Posso votar em respostas compartilhadas em Blogs/Redes Sociais?

Comment: Sinceramente, se alguma dessas perguntas tiver a resposta "Não", a filosofia do site perde completamente o sentido.

Comment: Randrade se eu não me engano, só existe um problema se tiveres uma percentagem (não sei qual) de votos acima de X numa só pessoa, uma agravante é se acontece o mesmo dessa pessoa em relação a ti.

Comment: @JorgeB. você quis dizer uma espécie de "troca de votos"?

Comment: @JorgeB. Nesta pergunta eu não falo à meu respeito ou a nenhum usuário do site. É uma pergunta ampla, para talvez evitar, dependendo das respostas.

Comment: Eu gosto da iniciativa, mas acho que é uma coisa que depende tanto, mas tanto de bom senso, que não tem como responder de maneira tão objetiva como talvez seja esperado. E não adianta dar muitos detalhes, pois tudo que puder ser explicado aqui pode servir mais pra mau uso e "contorno" do sistema (ou pra acalorar discussões)  do que pra ajudar. Mesmo assim, vamos ver onde vai parar, com o devido cuidado, dá pra sair coisa construtiva nas respostas, ou orientações sobre coisas que talvez nunca tenhamos parado para pensar :)

Comment: @Bacco Concordo com você, o real objetivo pode não ser alcançado (até acho complicado responder nesta pergunta, por ser tratar de um assunto complexo). Porém, acho que uma resposta da moderação sobre o assunto pode ajudar, visto que eu não encontrei nenhuma pergunta do tipo no meta.

Comment: Sem dúvidas posso afirmar que a resposta de todas as perguntas é "Sim". O problema surge quando aparecem os abusos, independente das contas serem de amigos ou não.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters sim isso, independentemente, se são amigos ou não, mas já se sabe que se forem da mesma "internet", como referiu o Randrade, há maior probabilidade de ser abuso. Como disse o Bacco, e muito bem, tudo depende de bom senso.

Comment: @Math Mas essa questão de "abuso" que é o problema. Por exemplo, digamos que eu tenha uma conta no twitter e poste cada resposta lá e que cada post gere 10 votos. Isso é considerado abuso? E se for 50 votos?

Comment: @Randrade é complicado. Vamos preparar uma resposta.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Tudo isto já foi respondido no [Meta Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com) ou no [Meta Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com), mas a razão pela qual estamos aqui, é porque nem todos falamos inglês mesmo, né?
Só refiro que já foi tudo respondido no MSE ou MSO porque a maior parte do que vou fazer aqui é traduzir o que já foi escritos por outros em inglês, para português — não vale a pena estar a perder muito tempo a tentar arranjar palavras melhores da minha autoria, quando já o que precisa de ser dito já foi dito bastante bem e sucintamente por outros. Tirado isto do caminho, vamos então a isso.

---

[Esta resposta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/138520/208518) responde, muito sucintamente, à maior parte das que estão a ser feitas aqui. Em particular, saliento a parte que responde a "**o que posso fazer para evitar que votos entre mim e os meus colegas de trabalho sejam considerados fraudulentos?**":

> Há muitas coisas que podes fazer, incluindo contribuir com conteúdo que não sejam votos, ainda que os votos que fazes pesem mais nas decisões dos moderadores nestes casos. Sem entrar em específicos, tenta pôr-te no lugar de um moderador por um bocado. Se 90% dos teus votos foram para o teu colega de trabalho, isso parece certamente mal, certo? Então e se forem 50% ou até 25%? Começamos a chegar a uma área cinzenta, mas honestamente não temos nenhuma linha definida em lado nenhum.
>
> O melhor conselho é evitar votar nos posts dos teus colegas de trabalho. Uma vez que não podemos esperar que deixes completamente de votar em tópicos nos quais provavelmente és perito, eu advertir-te-ia a votares nos posts deles com moderação, e certifica-te que passas tempo no site a contribuir com conteúdo e a votar em perguntas e resposta de outros utilizadores para além dos teus colegas de trabalho.
>
> Desculpa não poder ser mais específico, mas estou certo de que compreendes que se revelarmos exactamente como detectamos "voting rings" <sup><sup>(anéis de votos?)</sup></sup> e exactamente qual é a nossa tolerância para os mesmos, as pessoas iriam utilizar essa informação para esconder batota.

A secção de comentários na resposta tem ainda [uma porção que me parece relevante](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138517/how-to-vote-on-friends-colleagues-questions-or-answers#comment389684_138520):

> Considero isto um falso-positivo porque se me tivesse deparado com estas perguntas "organicamente" teria votado nelas. (...)

Ao que [o autor da resposta responde](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138517/how-to-vote-on-friends-colleagues-questions-or-answers#comment389694_138520):

> Referia-me sobretudo ao caso geral de colegas de trabalho votarem a favor de cada um em grandes proporções. Como descobres perguntas e repostas ("organicamente" vs. indo directamente ao perfil do teu colega de trabalho) não é um grande factor. Muitos utilizadores ganharam "fãs" que os seguem, e se olhasses para o meu perfil haveriam algumas anomalias só porque partilho alguns interesses com outros utilizadores. Nós esperamos ver algumas anomalias como estas nos utilizadores mais activos.

Parece-me importante fazer aqui uma pequena pausa, e salientar este ponto fulcral: é importante para a comunidade do site que os votos sejam dados com base na qualidade, precisão e relevância **do conteúdo**, e não **nos autores** das publicações.
O que quero dizer com isto é que, para além dos concelhos dados na resposta acima, **é importante que os votos não sejam *para o teu colega de trabalho/amigo/familiar*, mas sim para uma boa publicação, que pode ou não ter sido feita por ele.**

Como [esta publicação no Blog Stack Overflow](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/12/vote-fraud-and-you/) diz:

> A nossa postura neste assunto é simples: removeremos silenciosamente qualquer votação fraudulenta que detectarmos. Por favor não o façam. A longo termo, será **mais fácil ganhar reputação por publicar grandes respostas e perguntas do que a burlar o sistema.**

No entanto, tendo em conta o que tinha sido dito acima, "qualquer votação fraudulenta que detectarmos" não é facilmente definido. Portanto o melhor conselho, reitero, é **não votar em conteúdo postado pelos teus colegas de trabalho.**

Um moderador no Stack Overflow diz, [neste post no Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275197/same-organization-ip-address-with-multiple-users/275202#275202), e em resposta à pergunta "O Stack Overflow quer saber/importa-se se múltiplas contas estão a vir do mesmo endereço de IP?":

> Não, a não ser que se comecem a comportar como um voting ring de socks — o que significa responder apenas a perguntas uns dos outros, apenas votar nos posts uns dos outros, etc. Se utilizares o site normalmente então não nada do que faças vai atrair a atenção dos moderadores.

Adiciona ainda, em resposta a "Se estivermos a ter um problema na nossa equipa que afecta mais do que um de nós, é desonesto que um colega de trabalho faça uma pergunta para que eu ou um outro colega de trabalho votem a favor?":

> Sim, este é precisamente o tipo de comportamento que vai atrair a atenção dos moderadores e pode terminar em votos invalidados, contas suspensas ou até apagadas.

Gostaria de apontar para [mais um post ainda](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57682/how-should-sockpuppets-be-handled-on-stack-exchange), que não é bem sobre este assunto, mas que também me parece pertinente. Este fala de [sockpuppets/marionetas/fantoches](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sockpuppet), e de quando é que devemos considerar que estas são um problema:

> Há uma mão cheia de razões legítimas para manter múltiplas contas. Uma boa regra básica para identificar socks abusivas é: **se a segunda conta te permite fazer algo no site que a tua conta normal seria impedida de fazer, é abuso.** Exemplos disto incluem (mas não estão limitados a):
>
> - Votar nos teus próprios posts
> - Responder às tuas próprias perguntas com outra(s) conta(s)
> - Votar mais do que uma vez noutros posts
> - Apoiar os teus próprios argumentos (...)
> - Utilizar gratificações para transgredir o "rep cap"
> - Transgredir suspensões, bloqueios de qualidade, ou os rate-limits para postar perguntas/respostas/cometários/etc.

Parece-me relevante falar disto porque por vezes **há uma linha bastante estreita entre duas contas de duas pessoas claramente distintas que votam uma para a outra, e duas contas que parecem ser da mesma pessoa.** No primeiro dos casos — como referido mais acima — simplesmente anulamos os votos e entramos em contacto com os utilizadores para que não voltem a repetir o feito (excepção a isto é quando os votos são detectados e anulados pelo sistema, e não é necessária intervenção dos moderadores), a não ser que sejam reincidentes, sendo suspensos nesta ocasião. No segundo dos casos, no entanto, tendemos a simplesmente apagar a "segunda conta" e suspender e mandar mensagem à primeira, *sem qualquer pre-aviso para qualquer das contas*.
***O facto de por vezes ser difícil de distinguir entre duas contas de duas pessoas ou duas da mesma pessoa* é mais uma razão para voltar a reiterar o conselho dado já duas vezes acima: NÃO VOTES EM CONTEÚDO POSTADO PELOS TEUS COLEGAS DE TRABALHO.** O parágrafo acima é o que melhor explica porque volto a dar este conselho.

> **Fui suspenso por sockpuppetting e acho isto injusto; não sabia que não era permitido/foi um colega de trabalho entusiasmado/eu juro que foi o meu irmão gémeo malvado (...)!**
>
> Aproveita esta oportunidade para aprender como a comunidade aqui funciona/fala com os teus colegas de trabalho/envia o teu duplo para a linha de tempo mais escura.
>
> Depois certifica-te que não volta a acontecer. Todos cometemos erros, e não mantemos ressentimentos aqui.

---

A versão inicial desta resposta terminava a responder às quatro perguntas com que o post termina:

> Posso votar em respostas de amigos?
>   Posso votar em respostas de usuários que estão na mesma "internet" que a minha?
>   Posso votar em respostas compartilhadas por colegas de trabalho?
>   Posso votar em respostas compartilhadas em Blogs/Redes Sociais?

Tendo em consideração que **os votos devem ser dados com base na qualidade, precisão e relevância *do conteúdo*, e não *nos autores* das publicações**, vou antes responder a versões corrigidas das perguntas que me parecem mais pertinentes.
Note-se, ainda, que quando digo "é melhor não," não estou a querer dizer "não" — estou a querer dizer, precisamente, que **É MELHOR NÃO**; é um conselho, e não uma regra de ouro. Se quiseres saber mais detalhes sobre porque é que te aconselho assim, lê o resto do post acima, e não só a secção de resumo.

> **Se uma reposta for de boa qualidade, *e de um amigo*, posso votar nela?**

***Para evitar problemas*, é melhor não.**
A reposta mais longa é que se o fizeres, corres o risco de que esses votos passem por fraudulentos, e ainda de que uma (ou mais) das contas sejam apagadas ou suspensas.

> **Se uma resposta for de boa qualidade, *e de usuários que estão na mesma "internet" que a minha*, posso votar nela?**

Outra vez: ***para evitar problemas*, é melhor não.** Por razões óbvias... assim como na pergunta acima, pode resultar em suspensões ou removimentos de contas.
Para referência: é raro (se não inexistente) o caso em que um moderador *me* pede para invalidar votos entre contas que partilham IPs e eu não o faço. Aqui sugiro mesmo que evitem fazê-lo, porque correm o risco de que as duas contas sejam confundidas como sendo da mesma pessoa, mais do que noutro caso.

> **Se uma resposta for de boa qualidade, *e compartilhada por colegas de trabalho*, posso votar nela?**

Ver os dois pontos acima.

> **Se uma resposta for de boa qualidade, *e compartilhada em Blogs/Redes Sociais*, posso votar nela?**

Mais uma vez, ver os dois pontos acima.

Comment: Em resumo, **não votes em conteúdo postado pelos teus colegas.!**

Comment: Na minha opinião a melhor maneira de incentivar um usuário a responder melhor, seja amigo ou não, é através dos votos, isso quando a pergunta/resposta é boa.

Comment: "não sabia que não era permitido" e "eu juro que foi o meu irmão gémeo malvado" soam como desculpas esfarrapadas e ridículas que nunca são verdadeiras e que a SE já cansou de ver por aí de pessoas que de fato estavam fazendo sockpuppet. Colocar isso na mesma categoria de "foi um colega de trabalho entusiasmado" me faz pensar se a SE não está vendo essa situação como uma desculpa esfarrapada também, sendo que neste caso isso é mais provável de ser a verdade.

Comment: Além disso, imagine o cenário: Eu estou trabalhando em uma empresa desenvolvendo algum produto, esbarro em algum problema difícil, posto no SO a minha dúvida e aviso os meus colegas disso, afinal eles estão tão interessados quanto eu. Eles vão lá, votam, comentam, etc. Resultado: eu sou punido. Isso é justo?

Comment: @VictorStafusa Pelo que eu pude entender, não é nada assim "tão radical". Se seus colegas de trabalho utilizam o site, votam em outras pessoas, nada irá acontecer, pois é uma situação normal. Agora, se seus colegas só possuem votos em você, isso sim se classificaria a "fraude" comentada. Bom, pelo menos foi isso que eu entendi, caso esteja errado favor me corrigirem.

Comment: O Randrade está certo, pelo menos na maior parte do que diz, @VictorStafusa. Volto a reiterar o que disse na resposta e [neste comentário](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/5132/em-que-momento-votos-de-amigos-s%c3%a3o-considerados-manipula%c3%a7%c3%b5es-de-votos/5133?noredirect=1#comment18569_5137): se partilharem IP e eu me deparar com votos entre as contas, é quase certo que estes sejam invalidados — e recomendo aos moderadores a mesma postura. Depois, não é que nenhuma das desculpas seja esfarrapada, é só que não temos mesmo como verificar nenhuma delas...

Comment: (cont) pelo que se houver suspensão envolvida, o mais provável é teres que a cumprir até ao fim — o que é bom, para reflectires sobre o que aconteceu e o que podes fazer para evitar que volte a acontecer. Só se anulam suspensões se houver _provas esmagadoras_ de que cometemos um erro. Em relação a "eu sou punido," como dizes, não é bem assim: se não houver nada que indique que as contas pertencem à mesma pessoa, simplesmente anulamos os votos e comunicamos o feito a todas as partes envolvidas, para que não se repita no futuro...

Comment: (cont) e a partir daí, esse grupo de pessoas já sabe que se se continuar a portar daquela maneira vai voltar a cair no nosso radar, e aí sim serão suspensos.

Comment: @JNat cumprir suspensões nunca é bom. E sim, isso serve para punir, para expulsar usuários indesejados. É a mesma coisa que botar um sujeito na cadeia e dizer que é para ele repensar o seu papel na sociedade, o que é bonitinho, mas totalmente falso. A ideia é sim punir o indivíduo por algum tipo de má conduta (e por vezes pessoas inocentes são presas indevidamente).

Comment: Não, @VictorStafusa. Para expulsar utilizadores indesejados apagamos as contas destes, e bloqueamos o acesso ao site do endereço de IP de onde acedem ao site. O facto de um utilizador ter tido um lapso uma vez e ter cumprido uma suspensão não significado que é um utilizador indesejado, ou sequer problemático. Se os moderadores tiverem que o contactar e suspender uma vez por mês, ou assim, é outra conversa... mas uma vez é uma vez: todos cometemos erros, e ninguém se agarra a ressentimentos aqui — nem a equipa de comunidades nem a de moderação.

Answer (score 15):

> Posso votar em respostas de amigos?

Sim. Mas...

> Posso votar **só** em respostas de amigos?

Não.

> Posso votar em respostas de usuários que estão na mesma "internet" que a minha?

Sim. Mas...

> Posso votar **só** em respostas de usuários que estão na mesma "internet" que a minha?

Não.

> Posso votar em respostas compartilhadas por colegas de trabalho?

Sim. Mas...

> Posso votar **só** em respostas compartilhadas por colegas de trabalho?

Não.

Bem, acho que deu pra entender. Basta você não agir como um robô programado para votar em qualquer conteúdo de uma certa pessoa que não vai ter problemas.

Como moderador, eu entendo quando alguém vota muito em usuários que frequentemente dão respostas boas. Entretanto, algo fica estranho quando a mesma pessoa não reconhece o trabalho de outros usuários. Isto  caracteriza um favorecimento ilícito.

No caso de usuários na mesma "internet", isto é algo bem raro. Mesmo quando você tem um amigo que compartilha a internet, isso geralmente ocorre uma ou outra vez. Porém, 99.9% das vezes que dois usuários compartilharam o mesmo IP várias vezes nós identificamos que se tratavam de fraude.

Comment: Foi uma explicação mais resumida, obrigado. xD

Comment: Foi bem objetivo +1 :)

Comment: Só para clarificar: eu responderia que não a `Posso votar em respostas de usuários que estão na mesma "internet" que a minha?` Como disse na minha resposta, neste caso eu invalido sempre (não tenho na minha memória vez nenhuma em que isso não tenha acontecido). Não é que a resposta seja _mesmo_ `não`, mas não me ocorre caso nenhum em que votos entre contas que partilham endereços de IP diariamente não _pareçam_ fraudulentos: e quando _parecem_, vão ser invalidados.

Comment: @JNat Concordo. Meu "sim" se refere a um caso hipotético onde dois usuários válidos estão na mesma rede, mas ambos tem participação ativa no site e está claro para todos que eles não ficam votando entre si. Isto aconteceu há algum tempo com alguns usuários que estudavam numa mesma escola, mas é raro.

Comment: utluiz e @JNat estava agora a pensar e o que acontece numa universidade como a minha que tem um único IP para fora? Lembrei-em disto agora por causa do que disse o utluiz...

Comment: Aí, mesmo sem votos à mistura, o sistema pode acabar por bloquear ou pelo menos limitar o acesso ao site (ou pelo menos a possibilidade de postar) sem ser sequer preciso intervenção da nossa parte. O sistema faz isso porque toma vários utilizadores do mesmo IP a postar ao mesmo tempo como spammers, @JorgeB.

Comment: @JNat o que vale é que a maioria só consulta o SOen e não interage. Senão era complicado para a Universidade.

Comment: eu acredito que votar em respostas de amigos não seja errado a partir do momento que você tem a consciência do que está fazendo, vamos a um exemplo, meu amigo fez um post sobre html, nele havia um código errático que era quase incompreendivel, mais como ele é meu amigo resolvo dar uma chance a ele e voto positivo, estou errado?, sim eu estaria errado se eu fosse mesmo amigo dele teria votado contra ou nem votado e teria sinalizado o erro, não tem problema algum em votar a favor na pergunta de um amigo desde que você seja justo com os outros usuários

Comment: mas no caso da conexão no mesmo ip é um assunto muito delicado até porque muita gente utiliza internet compartilhada em universidades ou até  residencial mesmo, fica difícil dar um fim as fraudes.

Comment: @Nikk17016 Usar o mesmo IP é menos comum do que você pensa. E como eu disse, os moderadores investigam caso a caso.

Answer (score -3):

Eu acredito que seria errado a pontuação dada pelo amigo no momento em que a resposta dada pelo mesmo não atinge o objetivo procurado, e foge do contexto. 
Mas se o mesmo deu os pontos da resposta, e a mesma atende um contexto então acredito que não seria errôneo.

Comment: Aconselho-te a ler as outras respostas.